# How to call specific data from column database in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call specific value from field column in my database..

Let say i have table called posts, my table have field called `post_meta_title` and have value `home`
How do i call only that value to show in my meta tags..

I have tried it, and it show error `Property [post_meta_title] does not exist on this collection instance`

Does anyone know how to solved it?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your attempts.

Comment: Here's in my view meta `<title>@yield('post_meta_title', 'default title')</title>` `<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('post_meta_keyword','some default keywords')">` `<meta name="description" content="@yield('post_meta_description','default description')">`

Comment: Here's in my content

`@section('post_meta_title', $posts->post_meta_title)`
`@section('meta_keywords', $posts->post_meta_keyword)`
`@section('meta_description', $posts->post_meta_description)`

Comment: I call it at Controller `$posts = Post::all();` I don't know how to call specific value from field database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post_meta_title does not exist on `$posts` because `$posts` is a collection of multiple posts (Post::all()).

You can only get the post_meta_title from a *single* post. For example, you could do

```
$post = Post::first();
$post->post_meta_title;
```

or

```
$post = Post::find(3); // in this example, 3 is the post's ID
$post->post_meta_title;
```

or

```
foreach(Post::all() as $post) {
    $post->post_meta_title;
}
```

Comment: I have found the solution, i use query builder `$keywords = Meta::where('id', '1')->value('meta_keyword');` it allows me to directly get specific value from database.. Thankyou somuch for your help..

Answer (score 0):

because your `$posts` is a collection of object not model instance, to access `post_meta_title` you need to get it in a model instance:
foreach ($posts as $post){echo $post->post_meta_title}
or in blade

```
@foreach($posts and $post)
    @section('post_meta_title', $post->post_meta_title)
    @section('meta_keywords', $post->post_meta_keyword)
    @section('meta_description', $post->post_meta_description)
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have found the solution, i use query builder `$keywords = Meta::where('id', '1')->value('meta_keyword');` it allows me to directly get specific value from database.. Thankyou somuch for your help..